# Sporadic errors when reading textfile from share

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

A service running under domain account starts 20 ssis packages one by one to read 20 textfiles on a share.  One of the packages (always the "same" filename) fails sporadically: one or more successfull reads, then one or more failed reads, then one or more successful reads and so on.
This behavior used to happen for file A.csv but not anymore and the file B.csv is the current victim.  When the job fails I run succsessfully all the unfinished packages manually using the same domain account as the service uses.

"
Error during execution of package ...
Connection B failed validation.
The file name \share\folder\B.csv specified in the connection was not valid.
The file name property is not valid.  The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.
"

Internet search provides comments like privileges ons the share, folders on the path and the file it self.  But I think that is not the problem because the domain account does have these privileges and the reads (through the service) are sometimes succsessfull.

Any help will be well received

regards Bernódus

Comment: If it's possible can you please provide exact file name from error message instead of "\share\folder\B.csv" or exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try using path for shared folder with IP for example  `\\10.150.0.1\sharedFolder\B.csv` 
or without IP as `\\server\sharedFolder\B.csv`

If it's fail-pass then check whether that file is used by any other process\user, since it's on share so there are chances.

One of the workarounds is to have the network path mapped to a drive on the host server of the package.

You have make UNC paths to work on the calling machine, the server or the destination machine.

It could be a permissions issue.

Check permission on shared folder for -

1. Your personal Windows login account
2. Windows account which is owner of the SSIS Service

Answer (score 0):

We use to have a sporadic copy file to shared drive failure. Everything would be executing fine for about a few weeks or a month or so and then failed task with error on "Network path" or "login failure".

We found that the job was taking too long with one of the tasks and some how it was giving errors.
We had to modify the packages to improve performance to fix the problem.

1. Check your SQL Agent Job history to see if the tasks were taking a long time when the failure occurred.
2. Is there anyway to improve on the package performance or separate the package into multiple packages to run in SQL Agent one package after another

Hope the information helps.